# Rails 2.3.8 routing, how do I create a route without a controller name on nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Well I have the following code for routing with nested resources:

```
  map.resources :cities, :as => "cidade", :only => [:index, :show] do |city|
    city.resources :offers, :as => "oferta", :only => [:show], :collection => [:recents], :member => [:share, :buy, :add, :add_gift, :remove, :validate_buy, :want_more, :withdraw_credits], :path_names => { :want_more => "quero-mais", :recents => "recentes", :buy => "comprar", :add_gift => "comprar-presente", :share => "compartilhar", :add => "adicionar", :remove => "remover", :validate_buy => "validar-compra", :withdraw_credits => "resgatar-creditos" } do |offer|
      offer.resources :photos, :as => "fotos", :only => [:index]
      offer.resources :videos, :as => "videos", :only => [:index, :show]
      offer.resources :comments, :as => "comentarios", :only => [:index, :new, :create]
    end
  end
```

The thing is I don't want all those ':as =>' to be on the url, by this I mean that I don't want the controllers names on the url, istead of generating /cidades/curitiba/ofertas/1 I only want /curitiba/1.

I've tried :path_prefix and :as => "", but those did not work.

any help?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What if you try this after the map.resources definition in routes.rb?

```
match '/:city_name/:id', :to => "offers#show"
```

Then you do whatever you want in offers_controller#show

Comment: ive done this as a work around, but what I actually dont want do lose the nested resources.

Comment: if you add that line after the resources definitions you won't lose the nested resources.